# Sonar properties file - ignoring doesn't work

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

**Issue: I am trying to set the *sonar-project.properties* to ignore a module or a package and it doesn't work.**

I am totally new to Sonar and I'm using the eclipse plugin on a java maven project and I'm trying to ignore stuff (e.g. a package or a module) but the *sonar-project.properties* file doesn't seem to have any effect.

I have only one properties file in the root of my project. And there are 2 modules (one for java and one for webapp)

```
sonar.projectKey=projectname
sonar.projectName=projectname
sonar.projectVersion=1.0

sonar.modules=javamodule,webapp
sonar.sources=src/main/
sonar.tests=src/test/java
sonar.java.binaries=target/classes
sonar.java.libraries=../*/target/**/*.jar
```

If I try to exclude something like

```
sonar.exclusions=com/package/files/**/*
```

or

```
webapp.sonar.exclusions=resources/**/*
```

then I do analyze on the module and nothing was ignored. I also tried adding individual properties files inside the modules..

Also, I would like to ignore the whole webapp module. Should I just not declare it, or is there some other way?

**Edit:**

For example's sake, this is my package structure

```
javamodule
- src/main/java
    - com/package/files
- src/main/resources
- src/test/java
- src/test/resources

webapp
- src/main/resources
- src/main/webapp
```

Answer (score 1):

The SonarQube Eclipse plugin only takes into account exclusions set through the web interface. It doesn't take into account exclusions set in configuration files such as sonar-project.properties files.

Comment: why is that, since all the analysis happens locally?

Comment: The configuration of the project is retrieved from the server (that's why you need to configure the URL of the server). Then the analysis is performed locally.

Comment: So the only way to ignore locally would be through annotations.

Comment: How can I ignore a module? cause I see sonar.skippedModules has been deprecated